# Markdown multiline code blocks in tables when rows have to be specified with one-liners

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown, apiary.io

I have a table:

```
| YAY! | TABLE | \^^/ | 1-liner JSON column! |
| ---- | ----- | ---- | -------------------- |
| That |  has  | JSON | `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}` |
| Here |  is   | more | `{d: 4, e: 5, f: 6}` |
```

Is there any way for me to insert in multiline code blocks into a generated table cell?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Replace `` ` `` with `<code>` tags and use `&nbsp;` and `<br>`for indentation.

Similarly you can use `<pre>` tags instead of ```` ``` ````.

Comment: `<br/>` also works independently from `\`` or `<code>` to force multiline cells. I've used/tested this in combination with `pandoc` converting `my.md` to `HTML`.

Comment: I wasn't saying `<code>` was necessary for multiline cells, that was for making sure code formatting still happened despite using HTML tags

Comment: My intention wasn't saying you were either but to clarify for others that might not be aware of this fact! ;)
Anyway, I've run across Problems when using `&nbsp;` and pandoc to convert my `.md` to `HTML` as pandoc escapes `&nbsp;` to `&amp;nbsp;` which in turn gets displayed as **`Â`** in my browser. Did you ever come across such issues? To what formats are you converting your `.md` files and which tools are being used?

Comment: Oh! that makes sense -- As you can see from the tags I asked this question back when I was working with the Apiary tool in their 1.x version. I've since moved on right as they rolled out 2.x ...  it sounds like you want html-encoding to work in markdown when html-encoding is for HTML. Sorry I don't use pandoc enough to be of help

Comment: You'll need to use `<pre>` instead of `<code>` for multiline code block inside table on github ;)

Comment: Can't make it work guys, GitHub shows this code here on one line in a table cell, <br/> is hidden: `<pre><code>{<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;showToday: false,<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;showClear: false,<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;showClose: false<br/>}</code></pre>` Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @tonix Oh I make it work, you don't need `<pre><code>` just only `<pre>`. You can find a working example in my repo: https://github.com/prettier/plugin-pug/blob/main/README.md

Comment: `<pre> ... </pre>` is the way to go. Remember to make the second `pre` a closing tag `</pre>`

Comment: This really clutters up the readability of the Markdown itself, which kind of defeats the purpose. Can I assume that since this is the accepted answer this isn't supported in a more elegant way?

Comment: @Shinigami where is the working example? I can't see a table on the page you linked to!

Comment: There were many updates from then on, so here is a link to a historical version of my README https://github.com/prettier/plugin-pug/blob/6da73b20ee28475be8409aa76d9cbfec37570e26/README.md?plain=1

Comment: So there is no MarkDown way? This means that it's not possible to have nice table formatting when HTML is not allowed/supported (e.g. in the visualisation or README.md files on nuget.org).

Comment: Using `<br>` in CKEditor Markdown will brake your table.

Answer (score 16):

[Answer by @Meredith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24190674/6908282) is the perfect answer to this. I'd like to add more details and examples below

You cannot replace `` ` `` with `<code>` if you need to add other HTML tags inside the `<code>` element in your table cell. Instead you need to use backtick (`` ` ``) inside the `<pre>` tag like this:

Example:

| Markdown Input | HTML Output | HTML Preview |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` <pre> <p>Test Line</p> </pre> ``` | `<pre><p>Test line</p></pre>` | ``` Test Line ``` |

Extended Example:

| Markdown Input | HTML Output | HTML Preview |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `` `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}` `` | `<code>{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}</code>` | `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}` |
| ``` <pre> {JSON: <br> &emsp; ["Key1":"Value1",<br> &emsp; "Key2":"Value2"] <br> }</pre> ``` | `<pre> {JSON: <br> &emsp;["Key1":"Value1",<br> &emsp;"Key2":"Value2"]<br> } </pre>` | ``` {JSON: ["Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2"] } ``` |

Comment: From experience: this is unmaintainable. In my situation a html table was the solution.

Comment: I agree tyntam. If the OG question was regarding the maintainability of this, then I would not recommend this either.  But an example use case where this will be useful is for storing your markdown table in a database *(maybe for a blog CMS)* - if you use HTML table, you'll use more memory than you would with this approach. Especially, if only few of your table cells have multi-line markdown.