# How to add python code for markdown tables

Tags: markdown

Am I trying to make a table in markdown format and put multiline python examples there but the table is constantly shrinking and breaking.

```
| head 1 | head 2 | code block |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|
| str 1    | str 2    | <code>    |
| str 3    | str 4    | def example1():
                            print("Hello world")
                         </code>        |
```

Tell me who knows how to add multi-line python code to a table cell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown multiline code blocks in tables when rows have to be specified with one-liners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190085/markdown-multiline-code-blocks-in-tables-when-rows-have-to-be-specified-with-one)